# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012

Tags: oauth, nsurlconnection, http-status-codes, nsurlerrordomain

I keep getting this error when I make a request to an api. The api requires authentication and for this I add valid OAuth token to the header of the request. When I do that I receive a 200 response so all is good.

But I want to test my code to handle a 401 response code. To do this I add a invalid OAuth token to the request. I was expecting the server to just send a 401 response code but instead I got an error from my callback. The error is NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012, and after looking online it turns out this is a authentication error.

I was expecting the server to just send a 401 back? Instead I'm getting a error in my callback. Is there something wrong with my server or my request?

Thanks for the replies...

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to establish your NSURLConnection with a delegate to handle this the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I was using charles proxy and that was the reason I saw this error. When I stopped using the proxy it worked like a charm.

P.s. I've not tested this with NSURLSession but if anyone is curious just add a comment! :)